# MySQLi não consegue retornar métodos

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou mudando minha aplicação do PDO para o MySQLi já que só usarei SQL mesmo.

Crio a conexão no controller principal para que os outros herdem a possam abri-la:

```
class Controller {

    function __construct() {

    }

    public function openDB() {

        //$options = array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
        $this -> db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

        if ($this -> db -> connect_errno) {
            die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $this -> db -> connect_error);
        } else {
        return $this -> db;
        }

    }
}
```

Um exemplo de uso na classe filha:

```
class teste extends controller {

    function index() {

        $db = $this -> openDB();
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM teste WHERE id = 1");
        $stmt->execute();
    }

}
```

e me retorna isso:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in

eu dou um `var_dump` na variável `$db` para testar se a conexão está OK e ela me retornar um array normal...

Comment: A unica que noite foi a falta de selecionar o banco e dados.

Comment: Caramba, como eu não vi isso? e não deu erro nenhum rsrs, Obrigado!

Comment: Não selecionar o banco não da erro mesmo.

Comment: @rray posta como resposta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro acontece porque nenhuma base de dados foi selecionada, logo o `prepare()` falha e não devolve um objeto.

No método `openDB()`, adicione o quarto argumento no construtor de mysqli

```
$this -> db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```

Caso precise trocar de banco durante a aplicação pode utlizar a função
[mysqli_select_db](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php).